# Java: How can I read Struct type data in Java

Tags: java, struct, apache-kafka

I'm reading avro data from kafka and the value is of type `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct` and the value itself looks like this 
`Struct{f1=value3}`.

How can I read just the key(f1) and value(value3)?

Comment: How did you get a Connect Struct? If you're using an Avro deserializer, you get your object back by default

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the field, you can do this:

```
Object value = struct.get("f1");
```

If you don't know the name of the field, you have to get all fields:

```
for (Field field : struct.schema().fields())
{
    String name = field.name();
    Object value = struct.get(field);
}
```